# Return a column which meet two conditions with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to python, and here I have a question I don't know how to fix, please help.

Here is the thing: I have a dataframe, and I want to extract a column which meets two different conditions.

The columns is as follows:

```
     state gender  year       name  births
13299      AK      F  2013       Emma      57
13300      AK      F  2013     Sophia      50
13301      AK      F  2013    Abigail      39
13302      AK      F  2013   Isabella      38
13303      AK      F  2013     Olivia      36
13304      AK      F  2013  Charlotte      34
13305      AK      F  2013     Harper      34
13306      AK      F  2013      Emily      33
13307      AK      F  2013        Ava      31
13308      AK      F  2013      Avery      30
5742631    WY      M  2013     Emmett       5
5742632    WY      M  2013      Jesse       5
5742633    WY      M  2013      Jonah       5
5742634    WY      M  2013       Jude       5
5742635    WY      M  2013      Kaden       5
5742636    WY      M  2013      Kaleb       5
5742637    WY      M  2013      Kasen       5
5742638    WY      M  2013     Kellan       5
```

There is like 90K rows in this dataframe, I want to return the value of 'name' where the 'gender' column is as evenly distributed to 'M' and 'F' as possible.

Or in other words: I want to return the value of 'name' under the condition that 'births' columns contains same number of 'M' and 'F'.

Sorry I am new to Python, and I got stuck on this for quite awhile.
I was trying to split the dataframe into two different dataframe, and do it that way, but I found it was kind of impossible.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to read the data in a data frame. Use loop and condition.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot table in pandas works fine here:

```
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df,values='births',columns='gender',index='name',aggfunc='sum')
pvt[pvt['M'] == pvt['F']]
```

This returns a dataframe with name as an index and M,F for columns. It's unlikely that unisex names will be exactly equal though so you can instead do a multiconditional like

```
pvt[(pvt['M'] + 10 > pvt['F']) & (pvt['M'] - 10 < pvt['F'])]
```

Comment: Hi, sir. not sure if I were getting this right, but I printed your 'pvt['M'] == pvt['F']', and instead of giving me numbers, it gives me a whole bunch of True and False

Comment: yep, so that's a mask. It gives true false values when the value of a row in one series equals the value of the other. You're missing the pvt[pvt['M'] == pvt['F']]

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did a little bit more data cleaning and posted another question. Can you please help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088394/how-to-return-certain-rows-from-two-different-dataframes-that-meet-certain-condi

Comment: it's harder to do when you separate them actually. Did you try the code as pvt[pvt['M'] == pvt['F']] (note pvt in the front and that true/false statement in brackets)? That should return all rows where the values are equal.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to python. I was trying to do this way and searched 'pulling out rows from two dataframes' on google, didn't find much...

Answer (score 0):

I've defined `df1` to further process.  I've set the index to be `['name', 'gender']`, then `unstack` to get 'gender' into columns.  `.births` to focus on births.  Then I divide the min by the max to avoid dividing by zero.

```
df1 = df.set_index(['name', 'gender'], append=True).unstack().births.fillna(0)
df1.min(1).astype(float).div(df1.max(1)).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

This should give you a sorted dataframe by which name has a the closest ratio to 1.

Comment: Hi sir. I tried your codes, and I printed 'df1.min(1).div(df1.max(1)).sort_values(ascending=False)', but the result is just a whole bunch of 0s, and there's no number greater than 0

Comment: did you run it on the sample data?  If so, you didn't provide any name examples where there is any ratio other than 0.  Also, it could be a float, int thing.  I'll update my post.... Updated.